# How to filter data in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**View**

```
...
<span class="opensans size13"><b>Gender</b></span>
                <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="Gender">
                  <option value="" selected="">Gender</option>                      
                  <option value="M">Male</option>
                  <option value="F">Female</option>                       
                </select>   
            <span class="opensans size8" style="color: red;"></span>                                                    
            <div class="clearfix pbottom15"></div>

            <span class="opensans size13"><b>Published</b></span>
                <select class="form-control" name="published" id="published" placeholder="Published">
                  <option value="" selected="">Published</option>                       
                  <option value="YES">YES</option>
                  <option value="NO">NO</option>                          
                </select>   
            <span class="opensans size8" style="color: red;"></span>    
...

<div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="right wh70percent">
                    <select class="form-control" name="status_sort" id="status_sort" placeholder="Status">
                      <option value="" selected="">Status</option>                      
                      <option value="N">N</option>
                      <option value="BL">BL</option>                          
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

**Service**

```
public function dataCustomerList($param) 
    {
        $status = $param['status_sort'];
        $gender = $param['gender'];
        $published = $param['published'];

        if($published=='NO'){
            $published_check = 'NO';
            $published = 0;
        }
        else if($published=='YES'){
            $published_check = 'YES';
            $published = 1;
        }

        if(empty($status)) 
            $customer = customer::paginate(10);
        else
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.customer_status', '=', $status)
                                ->paginate(10);

        if(!empty($gender) AND !empty($published_check)){
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.gender', '=', $gender)
                                ->where('tb_customer.published', '=', $published)
                                ->paginate(10);
        }
        else if(!empty($gender)){
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.gender', '=', $gender)
                                ->paginate(10);
        }
        else if(!empty($published_check)){
            $customer = customer::where('tb_customer.published', '=', $published)
                                ->paginate(10);
        }
        return $customer;  
    }
```

The interface is like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxy48.jpg

When I just choose published and gender and then press the search button, data are displayed according

When I only select status, the displayed data in accordance

But when I choose the gender, published and status, the displayed data do not match

I want to ask again. In addition to my code, whether there are other simpler code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should build your query every time you add a filter, like:

```
    $customer = customer;

    if(!empty($status)) {
        $customer = $customer->where('tb_customer.customer_status', '=', $status);
    }

    if (!empty($gender)) {
        $customer = $customer->where('tb_customer.gender', '=', $gender);
    }

    if (!empty($published_check)) {
        $customer = $customer->where('tb_customer.published', '=', $published);
    }

    return $customer->paginate(10);
```

in this way you just add conditions and you don't need to check every single case and write again the same query

Disclaimer: I'm not a Laravel user, you could need to slightly edit the code, just saying the way to build the query

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The code becomes simpler. But it still does not work. When I choose the gender, published and status, the displayed data do not match

Comment: Have you checked the real sql query?